# Can AutoFixture create a list of objects for each possible enum that is a property of that class?

Tags: xunit, autofixture

I'm new to Autofixture but I very much enjoy the features it provides.

I have a class that handles different kinds of Push notifications, for each type possible I have an Enum.
I want Autofixture to create one object of each enum type, but haven't been able to do so yet.

My simple notification class looks like this:

```
public class PushNotificationModel
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public EPushNotifications NotificationType { get; set; }
        public bool EnableNotification { get; set; }
    }
```

With the enum:

```
public enum EPushNotifications
    {
        DailyConsumption,
        WeeklyConsumption,
        MonthlyConsumption,
        QuarterlyConsumption,
        Marketing
    }
```

I'm using XUnit to do the assertion afterwards.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate an enum

```
var builder = new Fixture().Build<PushNotificationModel>();

var allTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EPushNotifications))
   .Select(value => (EPushNotifications)value)
   .Select(type => builder.With(e => NotificationType, type).Create())
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That was exactly what I was looking for! :) Have a great day and thanks for taking the time to post.